# Right to left segue without pushing root view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I want to implement a horizontal right-to-left segue when clicking a bar button item in the navigation bar of the root view controller. I want to achieve this without pushing the root view controller aside, as I'd like the new view controller to sit on top with a blurred background. How could I achieve this? Any suggestions for how I could implement a custom segue? Thanks!

When using a push segue, the blurred background turns opaque (see below).

[GIF showing push segue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLGGP.gif)